# Why isn't pyinstaller making me an .exe file?

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I am attempting to follow [this guide](http://bytes.com/topic/python/insights/579554-simple-guide-using-pyinstaller) to make a simple Hello World script into an .exe file.

I have Windows Vista with an AMD 64-bit processor
I have installed Python 2.6.5 (Windows AMD64 version)
I have set the PATH (if that's the right word) so that the command line recognizes Python
I have installed UPX (there only seems to be a 32-bit version for Windows) and pasted a copy of upx.exe into the Python26 folder as instructed.
I have installed Pywin (Windows AMD 64 Python 2.6 version)
I have run Pyinstaller's Configure.py. It gives some error messages but seems to complete. I don't know if this is what's causing the problem, so the following is what it says when I run it:

> C:\Python26\Pyinstaller\branches\py26win>Configure.py
>   I: read old config from C:\Python26\Pyinstaller\branches\py26win\config.dat
>   I: computing EXE_dependencies
>   I: Finding TCL/TK...
>   I: Analyzing C:\Python26\DLLs_tkinter.pyd
>   W: Cannot get binary dependencies for file:
>   W: C:\Python26\DLLs_tkinter.pyd
>   W: Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Python26\Pyinstaller\branches\py26win\bindepend.py", line 608, in get
>   Imports
>       return _getImports_pe(pth)
>     File "C:\Python26\Pyinstaller\branches\py26win\bindepend.py", line 275, in _ge
>   tImports_pe
>       importva, importsz = datadirs[1]
>   IndexError: list index out of range
>
> I: Analyzing C:\Python26\DLLs_ctypes.pyd
>   W: Cannot get binary dependencies for file:
>   W: C:\Python26\DLLs_ctypes.pyd
>   W: Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Python26\Pyinstaller\branches\py26win\bindepend.py", line 608, in get
>   Imports
>       return _getImports_pe(pth)
>     File "C:\Python26\Pyinstaller\branches\py26win\bindepend.py", line 275, in _ge
>   tImports_pe
>       importva, importsz = datadirs[1]
>   IndexError: list index out of range
>
> I: Analyzing C:\Python26\DLLs\select.pyd
>   W: Cannot get binary dependencies for file:
>   W: C:\Python26\DLLs\select.pyd
>   W: Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Python26\Pyinstaller\branches\py26win\bindepend.py", line 608, in get
>   Imports
>       return _getImports_pe(pth)
>     File "C:\Python26\Pyinstaller\branches\py26win\bindepend.py", line 275, in _ge
>   tImports_pe
>       importva, importsz = datadirs[1]
>   IndexError: list index out of range
>
> I: Analyzing C:\Python26\DLLs\unicodedata.pyd
>   W: Cannot get binary dependencies for file:
>   W: C:\Python26\DLLs\unicodedata.pyd
>   W: Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Python26\Pyinstaller\branches\py26win\bindepend.py", line 608, in get
>   Imports
>       return _getImports_pe(pth)
>     File "C:\Python26\Pyinstaller\branches\py26win\bindepend.py", line 275, in _ge
>   tImports_pe
>       importva, importsz = datadirs[1]
>   IndexError: list index out of range
>
> I: Analyzing C:\Python26\DLLs\bz2.pyd
>   W: Cannot get binary dependencies for file:
>   W: C:\Python26\DLLs\bz2.pyd
>   W: Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Python26\Pyinstaller\branches\py26win\bindepend.py", line 608, in get
>   Imports
>       return _getImports_pe(pth)
>     File "C:\Python26\Pyinstaller\branches\py26win\bindepend.py", line 275, in _ge
>   tImports_pe
>       importva, importsz = datadirs[1]
>   IndexError: list index out of range
>
> I: Analyzing C:\Python26\python.exe
>   I: Dependent assemblies of C:\Python26\python.exe:
>   I: amd64_Microsoft.VC90.CRT_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.21022.8_none
>   I: Searching for assembly amd64_Microsoft.VC90.CRT_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.21022.8_
>   none...
>   I: Found manifest C:\Windows\WinSxS\Manifests\amd64_microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a
>   1e18e3b_9.0.21022.8_none_750b37ff97f4f68b.manifest
>   I: Searching for file msvcr90.dll
>   I: Found file C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.21
>   022.8_none_750b37ff97f4f68b\msvcr90.dll
>   I: Searching for file msvcp90.dll
>   I: Found file C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.21
>   022.8_none_750b37ff97f4f68b\msvcp90.dll
>   I: Searching for file msvcm90.dll
>   I: Found file C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.21
>   022.8_none_750b37ff97f4f68b\msvcm90.dll
>   I: Adding Microsoft.VC90.CRT\Microsoft.VC90.CRT.manifest
>   I: Adding Microsoft.VC90.CRT\msvcr90.dll
>   I: Adding Microsoft.VC90.CRT\msvcp90.dll
>   I: Adding Microsoft.VC90.CRT\msvcm90.dll
>   W: Cannot get binary dependencies for file:
>   W: C:\Python26\python.exe
>   W: Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Python26\Pyinstaller\branches\py26win\bindepend.py", line 608, in get
>   Imports
>       return _getImports_pe(pth)
>     File "C:\Python26\Pyinstaller\branches\py26win\bindepend.py", line 275, in _ge
>   tImports_pe
>       importva, importsz = datadirs[1]
>   IndexError: list index out of range
>
> I: Analyzing C:\Windows\WinSxS\Manifests\amd64_microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e
>   3b_9.0.21022.8_none_750b37ff97f4f68b.manifest
>   I: Analyzing C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.210
>   22.8_none_750b37ff97f4f68b\msvcr90.dll
>   W: Cannot get binary dependencies for file:
>   W: C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.21022.8_none_
>   750b37ff97f4f68b\msvcr90.dll
>   W: Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Python26\Pyinstaller\branches\py26win\bindepend.py", line 608, in get
>   Imports
>       return _getImports_pe(pth)
>     File "C:\Python26\Pyinstaller\branches\py26win\bindepend.py", line 275, in _ge
>   tImports_pe
>       importva, importsz = datadirs[1]
>   IndexError: list index out of range
>
> I: Analyzing C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.210
>   22.8_none_750b37ff97f4f68b\msvcp90.dll
>   W: Cannot get binary dependencies for file:
>   W: C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.21022.8_none_
>   750b37ff97f4f68b\msvcp90.dll
>   W: Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Python26\Pyinstaller\branches\py26win\bindepend.py", line 608, in get
>   Imports
>       return _getImports_pe(pth)
>     File "C:\Python26\Pyinstaller\branches\py26win\bindepend.py", line 275, in _ge
>   tImports_pe
>       importva, importsz = datadirs[1]
>   IndexError: list index out of range
>
> I: Analyzing C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.210
>   22.8_none_750b37ff97f4f68b\msvcm90.dll
>   W: Cannot get binary dependencies for file:
>   W: C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.21022.8_none_
>   750b37ff97f4f68b\msvcm90.dll
>   W: Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Python26\Pyinstaller\branches\py26win\bindepend.py", line 608, in get
>   Imports
>       return _getImports_pe(pth)
>     File "C:\Python26\Pyinstaller\branches\py26win\bindepend.py", line 275, in _ge
>   tImports_pe
>       importva, importsz = datadirs[1]
>   IndexError: list index out of range
>
> I: could not find TCL/TK
>   I: testing for Zlib...
>   I: ... Zlib available
>   I: Testing for ability to set icons, version resources...
>   I: ... resource update available
>   I: Testing for Unicode support...
>   I: ... Unicode available
>   I: testing for UPX...
>   I: ...UPX available
>   I: computing PYZ dependencies...
>   I: done generating C:\Python26\Pyinstaller\branches\py26win\config.dat

My Python script (named Hello.py) is the same as the example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python 
for i in xrange(10000): 
print "Hello, World!"
```

This is my BAT file, in the same directory:

> set PIP=C:\Python26\Pyinstaller\branches\py26win\
>   python %PIP%Makespec.py --onefile --console --upx --tk Hello.py
>   python %PIP%Build.py Hello.spec

When I run Hello.bat in the command prompt several files are made, none of which are an .exe file, and the following is displayed:

> C:\My Files>set PIP=C:\Python26\Pyinstaller\branches\py26win\
>
> C:\My Files>python C:\Python26\Pyinstaller\branches\py26win\Makespec.py --onefil
>   e --console --upx --tk Hello.py
>   wrote C:\My Files\Hello.spec
>   now run Build.py to build the executable
>
> C:\My Files>python C:\Python26\Pyinstaller\branches\py26win\Build.py Hello.spec
>
> I: Dependent assemblies of C:\Python26\python.exe:
>   I: amd64_Microsoft.VC90.CRT_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.21022.8_none
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Python26\Pyinstaller\branches\py26win\Build.py", line 1359, in 
>       main(args[0], configfilename=opts.configfile)
>     File "C:\Python26\Pyinstaller\branches\py26win\Build.py", line 1337, in main
>       build(specfile)
>     File "C:\Python26\Pyinstaller\branches\py26win\Build.py", line 1297, in build
>       execfile(spec)
>     File "Hello.spec", line 3, in 
>       pathex=['C:\My Files'])
>     File "C:\Python26\Pyinstaller\branches\py26win\Build.py", line 292, in __init_
>   _
>       raise ValueError, "script '%s' not found" % script
>   ValueError: script 'C:\Python26\Pyinstaller\branches\py26win\support\useTK.py' n
>   ot found

I have limited knowledge with the command prompt, so please take baby steps with me if I need to do something there.

Answer (score 6):

64-bit Python is not supported by pyinstaller under Windows. There's normally no drawback when using 32-bit Python under a 64-bit environment, though, so the easiest option is to install and use that. It also has the added benefit that a executable generated by pyinstaller will work under both 32-bit and 64-bit Windows.

Comment: Note for people finding this a few years later, PyInstaller fixed this some time ago.  See [bug #25](http://www.pyinstaller.org/ticket/25).